# Unable to change WordPress admin mail

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change my WordPress admin email. If I am doing from the WordPress settings, it is showing request pending, you will receive a confirmation email. But I am not getting any mail from WordPress. I also try to change it from the database but the changed email is not reflecting in WordPress.

Comment: since u have added in db., clear wordpress cache once and check... try not to override from code if using a purchased theme

Comment: Make sure you mail server is working properly on your server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the following lines on top of your active themes functions.php save the file
2. Reload your admin once then comment the added code

   ```
   update_option( 'admin_email', 'your_new_email@gmail.com' );                                   
   update_option( 'new_admin_email', 'your_new_email@gmail.com' );
   ```